# GetPlayerFromCharacter is returning Nil - Roblox/Lua

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have a sword script that only allows npc's to be hurt, not players. It creates a creator tag on any npc it damages. And if the npc is killed, it rewards the player with money (Or at least it's suppose to). I've done some debugging have found out that when trying to actually retrieve the player, it's returning nil. I can't for the life of my figure out why. I have done some digging around on google but nothing that helped me with my situation.

Script for sword:

The creator tag is created in the `if humanoid.Parent ~= tool.Parent and canDamage and not game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent) then` line. The player variable returns nil

```
local tool = script.Parent
local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(tool.parent)

local canDamage = false
local canSwing = true

local dmg = 50
local cooldown = 1.5

local function onTouch(otherPart)

    local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

    if not humanoid then 
        return 
    end

    if humanoid.Parent ~= tool.Parent and canDamage and not game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent) then
        local tag = Instance.new("ObjectValue",humanoid)
        tag.Name = "creator"
        tag.Value = player
        game.Debris:AddItem(tag,0.5)
        humanoid:TakeDamage(dmg)
    else
        return
    end

    canDamage = false
end

local function slash()
    if canSwing then
        canSwing = false
        local str = Instance.new("StringValue")
        str.Name = "toolanim"
        str.Value = "Slash" 
        str.Parent = tool
        canDamage = true
        wait(cooldown) --cooldown time
        canSwing = true
    end
end

tool.Activated:Connect(slash)
tool.Handle.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the root cause of the problem however the thing that stood out to me is that you access `Players` using `game.Players`. You should try to use the service players instead, as from what I know it has better functionality and is regarded as the best practice method of using `Players`

When I am going to access `Players` I usually write something like this at the top of my code:

`local players = game:GetService("Players")`

You should try this and see if it resolves the problem.

If it doesn't drop a comment and I'll see if I can figure out what the problem is.

If you do try this make sure you do this:

`players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent)`

and not:

`game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent)`